# How to ignore lines that starts with a blank character?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep

I have a udcli output that looks like these (Just assume that the commands perfectly makes sense, there were just made by random byte generator actually)

```
00000000000005b9 dc4753           fadd qword [edi+0x53]   
00000000000005bc 226d9e           and ch, [ebp-0x62]      
00000000000005bf 81a4a495dc47ff4b and dword [esp-0xb8236b], 0xe0076b4b
                -6b07e0          
00000000000005ca e667             out 0x67, al            
00000000000005cc 9acc27d432520f   call dword 0xf52:0x32d427cc
```

Notice the 3rd-4th line on which there is an extra line that extends form the 3rd line.

Now, what I'm trying to do is to get the difference on the address of the next line to the previous line. I'm doing this by using my own awk script.

My problem is, when awk read the 3rd and 4th line, it gives me an output like these

```
3   dc4753  fadd    qword   [edi+0x53]
3   226d9e  and ch, [ebp-0x62]
3   81a4a495dc47ff4b    and dword   [esp-0xb8236b],
-1471                                                   
1482    e667    out 0x67,   al
2   9acc27d432520f  call    dword   0xf52:0x32d427cc
```

where the 1st column is size of the instruction (difference of 2 addresses)

Now my question is, how can I make awk ignore that particular line so it outputs properly.
Is this possible with grep instead?

My current awk script

```
udcli file.out | awk 'BEGIN{getline; print "0\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5; a = 0; b = strtonum("0x"$1);} {a = strtonum("0x"$1); print a - b "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5; b = a;}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say for sure w/o seeing your actual awk-script, but something like this should help you on your way ...

```
awk '$1~/^000/' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^\s/ { getline }
    ... rest of script' < inputfile
```